# What should happen with a column after the primary key constraint was removed?

Tags: sql-server, relational-database, primary-key

I am talking about the normalization of a primary key. So let's say my primary key column is of type nvarchar, which violates the rules of normalization. After removing the primary key constraint and the identity specification from the desired column. I need to create a new column which will be the new primary key of that table.

My question is, what should happen with the previous primary key? 
I've got an answer that sounds like: "the column should became a semantic key", but i can't understand this answer.

Comment: The datatype has no direct bearing on normalization. Since you start with a false premise, the question itself must be "questioned". And one does not "normalize" a key - primary or otherwise. It seems you have a [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not unusual when designing a database schema to use a SURROGATE primary key.  The idea is to give each record a unique and permanent identifier so it can be easily referenced by applications and foreign keys.  This key has no meaning.  Knowing the surrogate key gives you no information about the content of the record.  The user of your application would never see this value.

On the other hand, your record may have a SEMANTIC primary key.  This is a unique value that identifies this data to that makes sense to the user.

For example, let's say you have a table of Employees.  The employer assigns each employee a unique Employee ID Number.  Let's say you store this value as a string.  To the user that value serves as the unique identifier that refers to that employee.  Meanwhile, your table may have a numeric column that serves as the unique identifier for that record.

```
create table Employee ( EmployeeRecordID int identity(1,1) primary key,
EmployerAssignedID nvarchar(12),
EmployeeName nvarchar(60),
Salary money )

insert into Employee ( EmployerAssignedID, EmployeeName, Salary ) values
( '#ABC100', 'Fred', 25000.12 ),
( '#AZZ314', 'Mary', 37700.00 ),
( '#MAA719', 'Fran', 34444.04 ),
( '#MZA977', 'Mary', 36000.00 )
```

As each record is added, SQL Server generates a unique EmployeeRecordID for each record, starting with 1.  This is the SURROGATE key.  Within your database and within your application, you would use this value to reference the record.

But when your application is communicating with the users, you would use the EmployerAssignedID.  This is the SEMANTIC primary key.  It makes sense to your users to use this value to search for a particular employee.

Comment: You didn't put a UNIQUE constraint EmployerAssignedID. Also you made it nullable. The point of a UNIQUE constraint is to make sure that identifier remains unique.

Comment: Thanks, @nvogel.  You are absolutely correct.  My intention was to explain the meaning of terminology with a minimal example.  Perhaps I could put together a blog post or something that goes into more detail.

Answer (score 0):

A primary key is no more than a unique index which can't have `NULL` value as a key. Like any of indexes it can be clustered or nonclustered.

Deleting a clustered index makes table become a heap with changes in structure and behaviour. Deleting a nonclustered index is just deallocation its space and does not affect that table and other indexes on the table as well.

So after deleting you just have a column(s) with unique values and you are able to consider them as a semantic key until some duplicate values are inserted.